# dc.piechart display percentage of row

Tags: dc.js

I have a data similar to :

[image]

I would like to display percentage of sum of each column with dc.piechart . It will look like below.

[image]

I can't figure it out as I am not sure how to build dimension and group for this kind of problem.

Comment: You aren't imagining it, crossfilter is designed to work with rows, not columns. However it is possible to hack. The following Q&A has a row chart instead of a pie chart, but it's the same problem. Note that you cannot meaningfully filter by clicking on the pie wedges, because filtering is only by row.

Comment: Yes !!. It worked perfect on piechart also.  I used it on my code. Thanks @Gordon